# Magento new created user can't add products - loads forever

Tags: php, magento, magento2

In Magento 2.4.3 I created a new user role Content Creator (Where it has access only to Catalog - add/edit products), assigned it to a user.

When adding a product as a Content Creator user and saving it, the screen loads for forever.

When I add a product as an Admin, it's all fine and works.

Tried this through ssh, but no luck:

```
cd applications/.../public_html
```

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

```
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento cache:flush
```

```
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento cache:clean
```